# No write permission even though defined

Tags: c, ubuntu-11.04

I want to create a file using the open().

Here is the part of my code :

```
int fd = open("testing", O_EXCL | O_CREAT, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO);
    if(fd == -1){
        perror("Error");
        return 1; }
```

The output should be a file named "testing" is created, with Read, Write and Execute permission for user, group and others.

But what I get is a file named "testing", with this permission :

```
-rwxr-xr-x
```

The write permission for Group and Others are missing.

I also tried using

```
S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IXUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IXGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH |S_IXOTH)
```

But I still get the same result.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Permissions are modified by the process' umask. Effective permissions are `(mode & ~umask)`.

You should change permissions after creating the file, using `fchmod()`. `fchmod()` avoids race conditions you could have if you used `chmod()` and the underlying file changed to point to other inode between the `open()` and the `chmod()` (google for TOCTOU races).

Comment: So, it's is not encourage to create a file, and at the same time set the mode?

Comment: Usually you should respect the umask, and then you can set the mode in the `open()` call. If you want to override the umask for a specific `open()` call, it's better done with a separate `fchmod()` call.